# CameraX and MultiCamera support

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax, multi-camera-api

Now we have `CameraX: 1.0.0-beta01`. Do you know if we can use [MultiCamera support](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera) in [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) now? Or, is it in the plan to add MultiCamera support to CameraX? I cannot find any development plan about CameraX.

Comment: "Or, is it in the plan to add MultiCamera support to CameraX? I cannot find any development plan about CameraX." -- Google does not normally discuss development plans publicly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. So I have a dilemma. Will I start develop. with Camera2 or will I wait to CameraX with next features?

Comment: The Camera2 API is rather complicated. If you can use a library to avoid it (CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.), I recommend it. However, libraries will not offer support for each and every Camera2 feature. If there are Camera2 features that are not supported by libraries but that you feel are essential, then you will need to use Camera2 directly. Just budget a lot of time for testing.

Comment: Yes I need advanced features: scenes, video recording, take a photos while recording, timelapse, ... I have it all with Camera API 1, and I would like to use all from Camera API 1 with CameraX, but it seems, that I can't do it with CameraX. So that's was my question about CameraX plans.. Thank you

Comment: Video Capture just released the first alpha in 1.1.0-alpha10. Multiple camera is not in the release.

Answer (score 0):

CameraX API currently ([1.1.0-alpha10](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera)) does not support Multiple Cameras.